# Create a navigation button like the iPod "Now Playing" button

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller

In the iPod app, there's a right-facing navigation button as well as the usual left-facing "Back" button. It gets you back to the "Now Playing" screen. Is this a custom button, or is there a way to easily create one using standard tools?

[alt text http://img.skitch.com/20100513-m9b9g67ftfh8bisgbj3mib9sex.jpg](http://img.skitch.com/20100513-m9b9g67ftfh8bisgbj3mib9sex.jpg)

Answer (score 10):

Not possible in the SDK I believe.  A workaround would be to create the button in Dashcode (search "dashcode" in the spotlight).  In the "Mobile Safari" view, just drag in a "Go Forward Button".  You can then recolour the image using Dashcode inspector.  Find the Dashcode project in Finder, right click it and go to "Show Package Contents", the button images should be under the image directory (Project > mobile > Parts > Images).

Then you can simply add the button to your Nav bar as an custom image UIBarButtonItem (self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = ...);

[Example http://img6.imageshack.us/img6/5372/screenshot20100515at220.png](http://img6.imageshack.us/img6/5372/screenshot20100515at220.png)

Comment: This would have been a great answer but it simply doesn't work.  You can indeed make an forward button but the text won't become two lines, even if you press option+return.  Also, in the output the button is there but without any text whatsoever.  Alas.

Comment: Sure, just pointing out that this didn't work to save others the inconvenience of trying it themselves.

Comment: I can live without the 2 lines... But how do you get the Retina image? (@2x)

Comment: I got it: just duplicate both the button's size, corner roundness, and stroke width (in the 'Inspector')!

Answer (score 4):

The Last.fm app has code to do this.  Look at `showNowPlayingButton:` in `UIViewController+NowPlayingButton.m`.  Works like a charm! :)

https://github.com/c99koder/lastfm-iphone

Comment: I seriously can't comprehend why this answer is the underdog. Thanks a lot.